# Step by step procedure to create webservice in spring

Tags: web-services, spring-security, spring-ws

I am new to spring web service. I am creating one project in which I have to move the Login service alone to seperate project and invoke the login service from different project. Please provide me suggestion how to implement this.

I am using spring security and created login service.

Please provide me detailed step to make login service as seperate webservice and how to call login service from another service.

Thanks

Comment: small tutorial on WS but not on spring-ws, you can refer it for start up http://java2practice.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/java-webservice-with-axis/

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for  spring-ws

Answer (score 3):

in detail explanation 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/index.html

step by step example
http://krams915.blogspot.in/2010/12/spring-ws-tutorial-using-latest-200-rc2.html

Comment: This link gives good examples of spring ws security
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?52204-Spring-and-WSS4J-Example

Comment: There's also a tutorial section in the Spring-WS reference:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html#d5e183 and an extra section for security: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/security.html